# Problema al diseñar programa para insertar número en array

Tags: c#, array

resulta que necesito diseñar un programa que lleve a cabo las siguientes acciones:

-Pedir un número entero al usuario.

A continuación, el programa pide tantos enteros como el número introducido previamente y los almacena en un vector.

A continuación el programa pide dos números enteros más: el primero corresponde a una posición y el segundo a un nuevo valor para insertar el vector.

Finalmente el programa ha de insertar el nuevo elemento al vector en la posición introducida. Si la posición introducida es negativa, el nuevo elemento se insertará en la primera posición del vector. Si el número introducido es mayor que las posibles posiciones de la lista, el nuevo elemento se insertará en la última posición del vector.

Me gustaría resolver los errores manteniendo la estructura del programa.

Me da 2 errores:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'   insert  C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\insert\insert\Program.cs  25  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int' insert  C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\insert\insert\Program.cs  63  Active

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
  using System;
    
    namespace insert
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int elements, position, change;
                Console.WriteLine("Insert total elements: ");
                elements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                int[] numbers = new int[elements];
                for(int i = 0; i<elements; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert integer value: ");
                    numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Insert position to insert element: ");
                position = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Insert integer value to insert: ");
                change = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("The final values for the array are: ");
                for(int i = 0; i <= elements; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(insert[i]);
                }
            }
            static int insert(int[] numbers, int change, int position, int elements)
            {
                int[] newnumbers = new int[elements + 1];
                if(position < 0)
                {
                    newnumbers[0] = change;
                    for(int i = 1; i <= elements; i++)
                    {
                        newnumbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
                    }
                }
                if (position > elements)
                {
                    newnumbers[elements] = change;
                    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
                    {
                        newnumbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                        newnumbers[0] = change;
                        for (int i = 0; i <= elements; i++)
                        {
                        if (i == position)
                        {
                            newnumbers[i] = change;
                            i++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newnumbers[i] = numbers[i];
                        }
                        }
                }
                return newnumbers;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Ha intentado que el nombre del namespace y el método no sean el mismo?

Comment: Sí, pero eso no resuelve mi problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi respuesta está enfocada en eliminar los errores de compilación, no hice verificaciones de la lógica del programa o si produce los resultados esperados.

Pude apreciar que, además de los errores en los que se enfoca la pregunta, el uso del `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` causará una exception si el usuario escribe algo diferente de números.

Los errores se producen por lo siguiente:

- En la línea 25 estás utilizando el método `insert` sin pasarle los argumentos, además el método está declarado para devolver un entero y debería ser un arreglo de enteros `int[]`.
- En la línea 63, `newnumbers` es un arreglo pero la declaración del método dice que devuelve un entero.

La declaración del método `insert` debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
// Debería devolver un arreglo
//        |
//        V
static int[] insert(int[] numbers, int change, int position, int elements)
{
    //... código omitido
}
```

En el método `Main`, antes del `for` que muestra el resultado, debes invocar el método `insert` pasando los valores a cada parámetro y asignar el resultado a una variable (para este ejemplo la llamé `resultado`).

Luego, utiliza la nueva variable `resultado` dentro del `for` (omito parte del código para mantener el foco en el área de interés)

```
... 
Console.WriteLine("The final values for the array are: ");

// Invoca el método insert
int[] resultado = insert(numbers, change, position, elements);

for (int i = 0; i <= elements; i++)
{
    // Utiliza la variable que contiene el resultado del método insert
    Console.WriteLine(resultado[i]);
}
```

Es cierto que la nueva variable `resultado` altera ligeramente el código de tu programa y también es cierto que puedes hacer la invocación del método `insert` dentro del `for`, pero no tiene sentido repetir la lógica del método `insert` por cada elemento del arreglo a mostrar.